# How to have just one trendline for multiple colors in plotly express scatter?

Tags: python, plotly, regression, plotly-express

I want to create a scatter plot with only one trendline.  Plotly express creates a different trendline for each color in the points list.

```py
import plotly.express as px

value = [15, 20, 35, 40, 48]
years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]
colors = ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']

fig = px.scatter(
    x=years,
    y=value,
    trendline='ols',
    color=colors
)

fig.show()
```

Is there a way to create just one trendline for all the points?

**Plot:**

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in feature for this at the moment, no, unfortunately! But it's a good idea and I've created an issue to suggest it as an addition: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1846

Answer (score 8):

With the release of Plotly `5.2.1 (2021-08-13)`using [`px.scatter()`](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/) lets you specify:

```
trendline_scope = 'overall'
```

#### Plot 1 -  `trendline_scope = 'overall'`

[image]

If the greenish color of the trendline is not to your liking, you can change that through:

```
 trendline_color_override = 'black'
```

#### Plot 2 - `trendline_color_override = 'black'`

[image]

The other option for `trendline_scope`is `trace` which produces:

#### Plot 3 - `trendline_scope = 'trace'`

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip",
                 color="sex",
                 trendline="ols",
                 trendline_scope = 'overall',
#                trendline_scope = 'trace'
                 trendline_color_override = 'black'
                )
fig.show()
```

---

#### Previous answer for older versions:

---

Since you're not specifically asking for a built-in plotly *express* feature, you can easily build on `px.Scatter()` and obtain what you want using `statsmodels.OLS` together with `add_traces(go.Scatter())`:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import statsmodels.api as sm

value = [15, 20, 35, 40, 48]
years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]
colors = ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']

# your original setup
fig = px.scatter(
    x=years,
    y=value,
    color=colors
)

# linear regression
regline = sm.OLS(value,sm.add_constant(years)).fit().fittedvalues

# add linear regression line for whole sample
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=years, y=regline,
                          mode = 'lines',
                          marker_color='black',
                          name='trend all')
                          )
fig
```

And you can have it both ways:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Change in code:** Just add `trendline='ols'`

```
fig = px.scatter(
    x=years,
    y=value,
    trendline='ols',
    color=colors
)
```

Comment: This will work until the feature is created in plotly.express ;)

Comment: @jgmh A good plan today is better than a perfect plan tomorrow =)